# Operator overloading with C++ : class with pointer datat members

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying a program to perform basic matrix operation using operator overloading. below is my code :-

class for holding matrix

```
class matrix {
    int r, c;
    int *data;

    public :
    matrix()  //default contstructor
    {
        r=0; c=0;
        data = NULL;
    }

    matrix(int a, int b)   //general matrix constructor.
    {
        r = a; c = b;
        data = new int[sizeof(int) * r * c];;
    }

    //Overloading + operator.
    matrix operator +(matrix & M);

             //Overloading = operator.
    void operator =(matrix & M);
};
```

then I have created a  temporary global object as below.

```
matrix temp;
```

I have overloaded + operator as below. Note that I have to use the global object 'temp' created above to save and return resultant matrix as one on my data member is int* and I cannot return objects with local scope.

```
// Addition of matrix
matrix matrix :: operator+(matrix & M)
{
         if(M.r != r || M.c != c) {
           cout<<"Addition is not possible!";
           return temp;
         }
         temp.r = r;
         temp.c = c;
         temp.data = new int(sizeof(int) * r * c);

         for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
          *(temp.data +(i*c +j)) = *(data +(i*c +j)) + *(M.data +(i*c +j));

     return temp;
}
```

ok, the program works well... but my question is **is there any efficient alternative to this external "temp" object?**

Comment: The `temp` copy is extremely likely to be elided, so the only inefficiencies you should worry about is when you have expressions such as `m0 + m1 + m2 + m2` where the `mi` are all matrices. A common solution to this is [expression templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates), but it is tricky.

Comment: Aside: your operators should be `const`, and act on `const` references: `matrix operator +(const matrix & M) const;`, and the size of your arrays looks suspicious.

Comment: Why would you declare the temporary object as a global? Just declare it as a local variable inside the function.

Comment: What @JoachimPileborg said. What I said about copy elision assumes `temp` is a local variable in the operator.

Comment: It's quite common to make the row and column parameters template arguments. E.g. `Matrix<4, 4>`. This makes it a compile-time error to add a `Matrix<4,4>` to a `Matrix<3,3>`.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any efficient alternative to this external "temp" object?

Yes (and also, there are some problems in the code).

The matrix sum should be implemented in two ways:

```
class matrix {
    // ...

    //Overloading + operator.
    matrix& operator +=(const matrix& M); // << notice difference in signature
};

// Addition of matrix
matrix& matrix::operator +=(const matrix& M)
{
     if(M.r != r || M.c != c) {
         cout<<"Addition is not possible!"; // this should throw an exception
                                            // because client code should not have to
                                            // be forced to check the contents of
                                            // std::cout to validate that the operation
                                            // succeeded

         return *this;                      // returning *this
     }

     // this is not necessary
     // temp.r = r;
     // temp.c = c;
     // temp.data = new int(sizeof(int) * r * c);

     for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
             *(data +(i*c +j)) = *(data +(i*c +j)) + *(M.data +(i*c +j));

     return *this;                          // returning *this
}
```

This is the concatenation (`+=`) operator and it's efficient because it doesn't create new/temporary objects. The problem it has is that it alters the left-hand operand.

Second implementation (as efficient as your first, and completing the code above):

```
matrix operator +(const matrix& x, const matrix& y) {
    matrix result(x); // you will need a copy constructor
    result += y;      // use operator defined above
    return result;
}
```

The second implementation uses the first to add addition semantics for matrix and it doesn't need to be a member.

Comment: Note that if you have written `operator+=` you don't have to write `operator+` yourself, use [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) or my [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/) library, the second allowing to optimize away some temporaries in expressions like `auto result = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4;`.

Comment: I know, but the OP is working on the correct signature and semantics of defining an addition operator. Adding 3rd party libraries, optimizations allowed by C++11 and/or inheritance, templates and CRTP to the example is a bit premature. I could have added a lot more improvements and advice to the code (e.g. use std::vector) but I wanted to focus on getting the function signature and (very basic) implementation correct.